# finding closest matching y point on another curve

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am not necessarily trying to find the closest point between the two curves but rather find the y point on the second curve that is the closest to the given y point from the first curve. Once I have the second y point it is trival to find the second x point.

The first curve is:
$$
y\:=\:a\cdot x^b-cx+d
$$
Where: $a\:=39.16360043$ $b\:=0.99999931$ $c\:=33.16339025$ $d\:=-3.01967162$

The second curve is a standard line
$$
y\:=\:mx+b
$$

Where: $m\:=2$ $b\:=-1$

Here is an example of both curves and 3 sets of sample points to illustrate what I am trying to do:
[Curves with lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds9g2.png)

Here are the points from the graph that intersect the first and second lines at the y points I am interested in

```
p1 = (74, 440.98727490205675)
p2 = (220.0, 439.0)
p3 = (80, 476.9876695944229)
p4 = (240.0, 479.0)
p5 = (86, 512.9880521151097)
p6 = (256.0, 511.0)
```

p1, p3, p5 are from the first curve and p2, p4, and p6 are from the second. Basically I am wanting to take any x value from the first curve, get the corresponding y value and then find the y value on the second curve that is numerically closest to the first y value.

Any suggestions as to how I can go about finding these points would be great.

**Edit** I do not have enough reputation to place the image inline sorry. After I posted this I noticed that the x values appeared to have a sinusoidal shape and after plotting them it is pretty obvious that they do. I think the solution would be to find that curve since the x values from the first curve would be the x values on this new curve and the y values of the new curve would be the x values of the second curve from above. Please see the plot of the [x values curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn7Po.png)

Comment: How is the "$y$ point which is closest to the given point on the second curve" not just equal to $y$ ?

Comment: they are approximately equal but not exact. for example here are two x,y points from the two different curves (74, 440.9872),(220.0, 439.0)

Comment: I am confused: Both curves take all possible $y$ values... so aren't they the same by definition? What else could „the closest $y$“ mean? Are you only allowing $y$ with associated integer $x$ ?

Comment: I was basically trying to find all odd integers that the 4th power mod 96 is 1.The second curve is all integers mod 2 = 1(odd integers) and the first was a rough curve I fit using scipy's curve_fit from all of those integers raised to the 4th power mod 96 = 1. The equation I posted in my answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There is a *much simpler* approach for this problem: Indeed, notice that $96=4\cdot 24$. Indeed this immediately implies by the binomial Theorem that $(n+24)^4\equiv n^4\pmod{96}$ for all integers $n$. So we only need to check what happens for $0\le n\le 23$. By manual work, we see that the following and only the following numbers satsify your condition: $n=1, 7, 17, 23$. Hence *all numbers $n$ that, raised to $4$th power, are $1$ modulo $96$ are of the form* $$n=m+24\cdot k$$ where $k$ is any integer and $m\in \{1,7,17,23\}$. Remark: Note that all such $n$ are odd

Comment: If you want, you can ask another question about this here and I will give a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to focus on the x points between the two curves. I now have an equation that will take the x value from the first curve and give me the x value of the second curve. In my edit above I posted a plot of the resulting x values curves. It was a linear line plus a sinusoidal shape. Here is the resulting equation

$x_2\:=(3x_1+25)+(3x_1^2+x_1 \pmod4)$

Giving me a final equation of

$y= 2((3x+25)+(3x^2+x \pmod4))-1$